# Parameter areas covered by white translucent will not trigger code hints in vs code, how to fix it?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

#### No hints in the parameters section, GIF here:

[image: Text]

I just want the white translucent area to not appear from the beginning.
How to do it? thanks:)

Comment: Does just hitting `esc` do what you want?

Comment: Yes, but I have to hitting `esc` twice to cancel selection, the first time it will close the function prompt, the second time it will cancel the white translucent area.

Comment: I just want the white translucent area to not appear from the beginning, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Search for `prevent` in settings, then cancel `Editor>Suggest:Snippets Prevent Quick Suggestions` ,problem solved.